# Using simple_html_dom.php and extract rows and columns but losing tags like <sup></sup> & <sub></sub>

Tags: php, dom

The table

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>text <sub>1</sub></td>
<td>text 2</td>
<td>text <sup>3</sup></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>text <sub>11</sub></td>
<td>text 12</td>
<td>text <sup>13</sup></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>text <sub>1</sub></td>
<td>text 2</td>
<td>text <sup>3</sup></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>text 12</td>
<td>text 22</td>
<td>text 32</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I want to extract all tr's and td' and store all td' in a database table row

I tried 
simple_html_dom.php

it works fine but removes/deletes/eliminates  tags like  `<sub>1</sub>`
in short  `<sub>1</sub>` is substituted by 1

I donot want to lose tags  `<sub>1</sub>`

Other way to resolve this 
Extract everything between `<tr> & </tr>`
**in an array** so that i can have each row stored in an array
with this i will  have (

```
$tr[0]="     
    <td>text <sub>1</sub></td>
    <td>text 2</td>
    <td>text <sup>3</sup></td>
     ";

$tr[1]="     
    <td>text <sub>11</sub></td>
    <td>text 12</td>
    <td>text <sup>13</sup></td>
     ";

$tr[2]="     
<td>text 12</td>
<td>text 22</td>
<td>text 32</td>
     ";
```

and then extract all  values and store them in database

i want solution to separate rows in an array (as specified above )
or
changes in  simple_html_dom.php to resolve this

any other solution ...

I even tried

```
$html = '<td class="header subject">T<sup>e</sup>x<sub>t</sub></td>';
//echo "<br>".$html;
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML( $html );

// Text
echo "<br>".$dom->getElementsByTagName("td")->item(0)->textContent;
```

but the tags `T<sup>e</sup>x<sub>t</sub>` are removed and i get plain Text

Comment: You example is overly complex.  Try and distill the problem down into something easier for someone new to the problem to digest.

Comment: i had restructured the question

Comment: tried $trstr = preg_replace('/<tr.*?>(.*?)<\/tr>/s', '$1', $html);
 echo htmlentities($trstr); removes <tr></tr> but could not store output i.e each row in an array

Answer (score 0):

following removes the unwanted tags

```
$str1 = preg_replace('/width.*?>/', '> ', $str1);
 $str1 = preg_replace('/<td style=.*?>/', '<td~> ', $str1);
 $str1 = preg_replace('/<col >/',  " ", $str1);
 $str1 = preg_replace('/<div.*?>/',  " ", $str1);
 $str1 = preg_replace('/<\/div>/',  " ", $str1);
 $str1 = preg_replace('/<span.*?an>/',  " ", $str1);
 $str1 = preg_replace('/<tr >/',  "<tr>", $str1);
 $str1 = preg_replace('/<table.*?>/',  "", $str1);
 $str1 = preg_replace('/<\/table>/',  "", $str1);
```

since `<table>` & `</table>` tags are removed (most essential)
preg_split could separate the rows in an array

```
$trr= preg_split('/<tr>/',  $str1); 
 echo count($trr); 
 print_r($trr);
```